# iOS App is crashing due to NSInvalidArgumentException - [_NSConcreteBlockSinkObservation superlayer] error

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

Here is the detailed error description that I am receiving in debugger bar

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[_NSConcreteBlockSinkObservation superlayer]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x6000005a4000'

Why this is happening and what will be the solution to it?

Update:

I tried to remove some lines of code for testing, then I found another error like below

> [__NSDictionaryM superlayer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6000008e8ee0

Comment: you app unable to find function in code.

Comment: Show the stacktrace. Can you locate on what screen, what steps to reproduce? Because "unrecognized selector sent to instance " is a well known error, but plenty of possible causes.

Comment: To answer your question: this is happening because somewhere in your code you are trying to call a method called `superlayer` on and object that doesn't implement it (_NSConcreteBlockSinkObservation). The solution to it would be find where in the code this happens and fix it...without any code that's probably the most that we can help.